# Getting Number of Cubes with Integer Coordinates with Certain Distance from Origin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, pool, voxel

I am working on a voxel system for my game that uses dynamic loading of chunks. To optimize it, I have a pool of chunks and a render distance, and what I want to do is fill the pool with a proper amount of chunks. So, I need a way to find that amount. I have tried the following but it seems very inefficient.

```
private void CreatePool()
{
    int poolSize = 0;
    for (int x = -m_RenderDistance; x <= m_RenderDistance; x++) {
        for (int y = -m_RenderDistance; y <= m_RenderDistance; y++) {
            for (int z = -m_RenderDistance; z <= m_RenderDistance; z++) {
                if (Position3Int.DistanceFromOrigin(new Position3Int(x, y, z)) <= m_RenderDistance)
                    poolSize++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More formally, the question involes finding the amount of unique cubes with integer coorindates with a certain distance from the origin.

If you think there is a better way to approach this or I am doing something fundamentally wrong, let me know.

Thanks,

Quintin

Comment: `int v = (m_RenderDistance*2)+1; poolSize = v * v * v;`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume its the distance check that you think is inefficient? What you've got shouldn't be too bad if you're just getting the count on Start() or Awake().

Draco18s solution is fine if you are okay with a cubed result. If you want a spherical result without a distance check, you can try some formulation of the volume of a sphere: 4/3*PI*r^3

checkout [Bresenham's circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

Here's a approximation algorithm for a filled 3d Bresenham Circle that I have. It is very similar to what you have already, just with a more effecient squared dist check and a minor adjustment to get a more attractive bresenham-looking circle):

```
    public static List<Vector3> Get3DCircleKeys(int radius){
        List<Vector3> keys = new List<Vector3>();

        for(int y=-radius; y<=radius; y++){
            for(int x=-radius; x<=radius; x++){
                for(int z =-radius; z<=radius; z++){
                    // (+ radius*.08f) = minor modification to match Bresenham result
                    if(x*x+y*y+z*z <= radius*radius + radius*.08f){ 
                        keys.Add(new Vector3(x,y,z));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return keys;
    }
```

This, however, will deliver a different count than the volume of sphere would give you, but with some tweaking to it or to the sphere volume calculation, it could be *good enough*, or at least, more efficient than instantiating a full volume of a cube, where many of the voxels will be outside of the bounds of the render distance.